# Django Custom Tables Creation

Tags: django, django-models

I have a project where i have to create a command table for the customers to command on the site. What I am trying to achieve is to give the possibility of selecting multiple products to the customer. The foreign key is ok for one product, but when we have to select multiple ones, is not ok. Even when clicking the "+"add button, you are not allowed to add more, but django makes you add a new product in the DB :D.

How can i achieve my target of adding multiple products to the cart?
[image]

Thank you in advance!

My models;

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
today = datetime.now().date()


class ClientManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ClientManager, self).filter(timestamp__lte=datetime.now())


class Client(models.Model):
    TYPE_CLIENT = (
        ('PF', 'Persoana Fizica'), ('PJ', 'Persoana Juridica'),)
    MODEL_CLIENT = (
        ('O', 'On-line'), ('S', 'Showroom'), ('D', 'Distribuitor'))

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, default=1, on_delete=True)
    model_client = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, default="PF", null=True,
                                    choices=MODEL_CLIENT, help_text='Selecteaza de unde vine clientul')

    tip_client = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, default="PF", null=True,
                                   choices=TYPE_CLIENT, help_text='Selecteaza tipul de client')
    nume_client = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default="", null=True,
                                     help_text='Insereaza Numele si Prenumele Clientului')
    adresa_client = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default="", null=True,help_text='Insereaza Adresa Clientului')
    cnp_client = models.CharField(
        max_length=12, blank=True, default="", null=True, help_text='Insereaza CNP-ul Clientului')
    serie_numar_client = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="", null=True,help_text='Insereaza Seria si Numarul Clientului')
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    nume_firma = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default="",null=True, help_text='Insereaza Numele Firmei')
    cui_firma=models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, default="",null=True, help_text='Insereaza CUI-ul Firmei')
    adresa_firma = models.CharField(
        max_length=70, blank=True, default="", null=True, help_text='Insereaza Adresa Firmei')


    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = ClientManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nume_client) + " | " + str(self.adresa_client) + " | " + str(self.adresa_firma) + " | " + str(self.nume_firma) + " | "  + str(self.timestamp)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "client"
        ordering = ["-timestamp"]


class ProdusManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProdusManager, self).filter(timestamp__lte=datetime.now())

class Produs(models.Model):


    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             blank=True, null=True, default=1, on_delete=True)
    nume_produs = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True,
                                help_text='Adauga Nume Produs')

    pret_produs = models.IntegerField(blank=True,  null=True,help_text='Introdu Pretul Produsului')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = ProdusManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nume_produs) + " | " + str(self.pret_produs) 

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "produs"
        ordering = ["-timestamp"]


class ComandaManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ComandaManager, self).filter(timestamp__lte=datetime.now())


class Comanda(models.Model):
    STATUS_PRODUS = (
        ('S', 'Stoc'), ('SD', 'Stoc Distribuitor'), ('L', 'Livrat'))
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             blank=True, null=True, default=1, on_delete=True)
    nume_client_comanda = models.ForeignKey(
        Client, related_name='nume_client_comanda', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nume_firma_comanda = models.ForeignKey(
        Client, related_name='nume_firma_comanda', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    produsul_comandat = models.ForeignKey(
        Produs, related_name='produsul_comandat', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pretul_comandat = models.ForeignKey(
        Produs, related_name='pretul_comandat', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantitate = models.IntegerField (blank = True,  null = True, help_text = 'Introdu Cantitatea Produsului')
    status_produs = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, default="PF", null=True,
                                     choices=STATUS_PRODUS, help_text='Selecteaza de unde vine clientul')
    pret_comanda = models.IntegerField(
        blank=True,  null=True, help_text='Introdu Pretul Comenzii')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = ComandaManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nume_client_comanda) + " | " + str(self.pret_comanda)
    #    def __str__(self):
    #     return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "comanda"
        ordering = ["-timestamp"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [Many to Many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationship, not [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) (Many-to-One)

This way multiple Clients can each have multiple Products.

Right now, two different Clients cannot have the same Product because you used ForeignKey.